# DataGridView Rows.Remove

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this code to fill my datagridview from my database.

```
string query = "SELECT * From guestinfo";

        using (con)
        {
            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4;
                    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "RoomNumber";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Room Number";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName= "RoomNumber";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "GuestName";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Guest Name";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "GuestName";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "RoomType";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Room Type";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "RoomType";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Status";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Status";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Status";                     
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    dataGridView1.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCellsExceptHeaders);}}}
```

And this code to remove the rows with empty value.

```
    for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
                        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridViewRow.Cells)
                        {
                            string val = cell.Value as string;
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
                            {
                                if (!dataGridViewRow.IsNewRow)
                                {
                                    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridViewRow);                                       
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

This Codes works but when I Add This code some runtime error happened.It Removes all my data. Even it is not empty.

```
                            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "CheckDate";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Check Date";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "CheckDate";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "OutDate";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Out Date";
                    dataGridView1.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "OutDate";
```

[image]

Comment: Show your "guestinfo" table.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlpyI.png

Comment: remove this block if (!dataGridViewRow.IsNewRow) and then try

Comment: @viveknuna not working

Comment: Are you sure? You are not binding GridView with same datascource again

Comment: All working but when you add columns 4 and 5 with dates grid will be empty?

Comment: Remove row from DataTable and then bind GridView, it will work

Comment: @mww yes, its empty

Comment: Maybe add formatting cell for both datetime columns like:  "dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

Comment: Still not working